# White border around single image in html document

Tags: html, css, image, png

I have a quick question, I'm making a simple html document, with an image that I want to fill the entire page.

For some reason, it wants to create a border around the image. I've tried border="0"; and padding 0px 0px 0px 0px;

Here is the code in which I have: (You can also check it out live if you prefer www.kidbomb.com/chefwannabe)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Pre-Order Now!</title>
</head>
<body>

<img style="width: 100%; overflow:hidden;" src="http://www.kidbomb.com/chefwannabe/chefwannabepreview.png" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you referring to the white space on the edges of the image?

Comment: Yes, the ones that surround the image on all sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following CSS in your code. Default body will give some margin and padding. So better whenever you start new work, add this style in your css for getting the proper result.

```
body
{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, I knewe it was something simple... I feel incredibly stupid right now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the img tag, set the background-image property of the body tag so it encompasses the entirety of the page.

```
body { 
    background-image: url("path/to/image.jpg");    
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I just edited to add a bit of code formatting. For multi-line code blocks, select the entire block and do Ctrl + K. For in-line code elements, enclose them within `\``.